# Spring cloud config client to get plain text file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

The spring cloud config server can serve plain text files as described here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html

I am able to get the plain text file if I curl the cloud server url as 
curl http://config.server:8001/config-server/ConfigData/default/master/plainTxtFile.json (file is in private github repo.)

So in a spring boot application, which uses config server as to get the configuration I can also get the file by accessing the above url via code.

Is there a way where I can define a 'configClient' and access file as configClient.getResource(), rather than getting it from url

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately:

> This was not implemented in the open source project.

See: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/789

Comment: Do you know is this feature implemented? If yes, could you send me some article about it?